# no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Predicate<String> conforms to Predicate<? super T>

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to configure Swagger using this configuration:

```
      import java.util.function.Predicate;
      import static com.google.common.base.Predicates.or;

      @Bean
      public Docket smartroutingApi() {
        
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .paths(getPaths()).build();
      }
       
      private Predicate<String> getPaths() {
        return or(regex("/v1/.*"), regex("/internal/v1/.*"), regex("/v2/.*"));
      }
```

But I get error message for `(regex("/v1/.*"), regex("/internal/v1/.*"), regex("/v2/.*")`:

```
Required type
Provided
components:
Predicate<? super T>...
java.util.function.Predicate<String>


java.util.function.Predicate<String>


java.util.function.Predicate<String>
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Predicate<String> conforms to Predicate<? super T>
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What is the signature of `regex`?

Comment: `  public static Predicate<String> regex(final String pathRegex) {`  https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-core/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/builders/RequestHandlerSelectors.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava [`Predicates.or`](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#or-com.google.common.base.Predicate...-) deals with [Guava `Predicate`s](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html), not [Java `Predicate`s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html).

You can either:

- Use `java.util.Predicate.or`:

  ```
  regex("/v1/.*").or(regex("/internal/v1/.*")).or(regex("/v2/.*"))
  ```
- Convert your `java.util.Predicate`s to Guava predicates, and then convert it back to a Java `Predicate` at the end:

  ```
  or(regex("/v1/.*")::test, regex("/internal/v1/.*")::test, regex("/v2/.*")::test)::apply
  ```